# Create a new Map using two different maps

Tags: java, dictionary

How do I create a new Map using the values from two existing maps.

First Map

```
Map <ID, name>
```

Second Map

```
Map <ID, email>
```

IDs are the same object.

How do I iterate over these two maps, to get name and email to create a new Map like
below ? Assuming The String values are unique.

```
Map <name, email>
```

Comment: are name and email strings or objects?

Comment: Be careful! While IDs are probably unique, names are not.  If you do what you are asking and have two distinct users, with different ID values but the same name, for example `{ID=1,name="John Smith"}` and `{ID=2,name="John Smith"}`, then after you create the map you will have lost one of the email addresses and you can't know which one in advance given the random order of `Map` iteration.  What you are asking to do does not make sense.

Comment: @Archangel33 ID is object, name and email are Strings

Comment: @JimGarrison is right. I removed my answer because while easy to do, it's not a smart idea for obvious reasons. If you really want to create such a mapping, it would be better to do using code that will specifically give you what you want, given that you already have two maps with the desired information, using the same key instead.

Comment: @JimGarrison I used name, email as an example. I'm trying to figure out the logic to do this action.

Comment: @RNJ's answer will work if you handle duplicates in a manner consistent with whatever your requirements are.  If not you will potentially lose data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that name is unique then you could do something like this.

Ive havent compiled this but it should give you the rough idea.

```
Map<Object, Object> res = new Hashmap();
Set<Object> keys= firstMap.keySet();
for (Object key : keys) {
    res.put(firstMap.get(key), secondmap.get(key);
}
```